# How to change svg color on hover with <symbol> tag unabled?

Tags: html, css, svg

please if you have any advice that can help me with this it would be most helpful and appreciated.

```
 <svg class="icon1">
    <use href="#svg"></use>
    </svg>
    
    
    <svg id="hidethis" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">
      <symbol id="svg">
      <path class="changeColor" fill="#FFF" d="M10 0C4.478 0 0 4.477 0 10c0 4.237 2.636 7.855 6.356 9.312-.088-.791-.167-2.005.035-2.868.182-.78 1.172-4.97 1.172-4.97s-.299-.6-.299-1.486c0-1.39.806-2.428 1.81-2.428.852 0 1.264.64 1.264 1.408 0 .858-.545 2.14-.828 3.33-.236.995.5 1.807 1.48 1.807 1.778 0 3.144-1.874 3.144-4.58 0-2.393-1.72-4.068-4.177-4.068-2.845 0-4.515 2.135-4.515 4.34 0 .859.331 1.781.745 2.281a.3.3 0 01.069.288l-.278 1.133c-.044.183-.145.223-.335.134-1.249-.581-2.03-2.407-2.03-3.874 0-3.154 2.292-6.052 6.608-6.052 3.469 0 6.165 2.473 6.165 5.776 0 3.447-2.173 6.22-5.19 6.22-1.013 0-1.965-.525-2.291-1.148l-.623 2.378c-.226.869-.835 1.958-1.244 2.621.937.29 1.931.446 2.962.446 5.522 0 10-4.477 10-10S15.522 0 10 0z"/>
      </symbol>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you remove the fill property from the path and style it with css instead, applying it to the svg element.

You can simply do this:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.icon1 {
  fill: white;
  transition: .3s fill;
  background: black;
}
.icon1:hover {
  fill: red;
}
#hidethis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon1" width="120" height="120">
  <use href="#svg" ></use>
</svg>

<svg id="hidethis" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path class="changeColor" d="M10 0C4.478 0 0 4.477 0 10c0 4.237 2.636 7.855 6.356 9.312-.088-.791-.167-2.005.035-2.868.182-.78 1.172-4.97 1.172-4.97s-.299-.6-.299-1.486c0-1.39.806-2.428 1.81-2.428.852 0 1.264.64 1.264 1.408 0 .858-.545 2.14-.828 3.33-.236.995.5 1.807 1.48 1.807 1.778 0 3.144-1.874 3.144-4.58 0-2.393-1.72-4.068-4.177-4.068-2.845 0-4.515 2.135-4.515 4.34 0 .859.331 1.781.745 2.281a.3.3 0 01.069.288l-.278 1.133c-.044.183-.145.223-.335.134-1.249-.581-2.03-2.407-2.03-3.874 0-3.154 2.292-6.052 6.608-6.052 3.469 0 6.165 2.473 6.165 5.776 0 3.447-2.173 6.22-5.19 6.22-1.013 0-1.965-.525-2.291-1.148l-.623 2.378c-.226.869-.835 1.958-1.244 2.621.937.29 1.931.446 2.962.446 5.522 0 10-4.477 10-10S15.522 0 10 0z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you this worked but there is also one more issue here that I just noticed that if I added a background color to the SVG of class icon1 it has way more space than it needs and if I hover even not over the icon it still changes red do you know also how I can fix this?

Comment: Sure, just set width and height in the icon1 element. I changed the code to fix that

Comment: Thanks a-lot your amazing!! (^_^)